# Spark: Mapping an RDD of HBase row keys to an RDD of values

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

I have an RDD that contains HBase row keys. The RDD is relatively large to fit in memory. I need to get an RDD of values for each of the provided key. Is there a way to do something like this:

```
keys.map(key => table.get(new Get(key)))
```

So the question is how can I obtain an instance of HTable inside map task? Should I instantiate an HConnection for every partition, and then obtain HTable instance from it, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few options you can can do but first consider the fact that spark does **not** allow you to create RDDs of RDDs. So really that leaves you with two options

1. a list of RDDs
2. A Key/value RDD

I would highly recommend the second one as a list of RDDs could end with you needing to perform a lot of reduces which could massively increase the number of shuffles you need to perform. With that in mind I would recommend you use a flatMap.

So here is some basic skeleton code that could get you that result

```
val input:RDD[String]
val completedRequests:RDD[(String, List[String]) = input.map(a => (a, table.get(new Get(a)))
val flattenedRequests:RDD[(String, String) = completedRequests.flatMap{ case(k,v) => v.map(b =>(k,b))
```

You can now handle the RDD as one object, reduceByKey if you have a particular piece of information you need from it, and now spark will be able to access the data with optimal parallelism.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, but I meant something different: the question is about getting an HTable instance inside map task. I've edited my question for clarification.